# what is the relationship between image size and font size?

Tags: image-processing

I'm working in image processing project, and I have this problem:

If I made a picture from paint and draw an character on it "IN FONT SIZE 12",
then import this image to a project that make cropping for text area.

So what is the relation ship between image width, height and font size?

i.e : The resolution of cropping image for font 12 is: 5×6 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship between font size and an image is entirely dependent on the code (i.e. application) used to create the font. For example, in Windows you generally give the size in points and the program is required to convert this to pixels. The conversion is based on a resolution in dots per inch, and will typically use either the screen resolution or the resolution of the image (if it has one).